# List of hidden achievements in Cities: Skylines

Tags: achievements, cities-skylines

I'm not able to figure out how to get the hidden achievements. Currently there are 14 displayed as hidden in my Steam stats. Does somebody know what these achievements are about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Achievements wiki page](http://www.skylineswiki.com/Achievements) lists all of the hidden achievements. They are:

- Put Some Blimp in Your Blimp
- Totally in Motion
- It's Called Steve
- Centurion
- Nomen Est Omen
- Combo Breaker!
- Not So Mono
- Blimp? Blimp.
- Cables Galore
- Clark Cable
- Triorail
- Ferry Faerie
- Rejoice and Be Ferry
- Reporting!
- Frenetic Player

The conditions for these achievements are laid out on [this page](https://www.exophase.com/game/cities-skylines-steam/achievements/):

> - Put Some Blimp in Your Blimp: Have 10 Blimp lines
> - Totally in Motion: Win all three Mass Transit Scenarios
> - It's Called Steve: Name a road "Steve"
> - Centurion: Name 100 roads
> - Nomen est Omen: Name a road
> - Combo Breaker!: Have one of each combination transport building
> - Not So Mono: Have 10 monorail lines
> - Blimp? Blimp.: Have 3 blimp lines
> - Cables Galore: Have 10 cable car lines
> - Clark Cable: Have 3 cable car lines
> - Triorail: Have 3 monorail lines
> - Ferry Faerie: Have 15 ferry lines
> - Rejoice and Be Ferry: Have 3 ferry lines
> - Reporting!: Check a route of a citizen
> - Frenetic Player: Click a Police Station 100 times